# Failed when using the filter_query in style_data_conditional in dashtable

Tags: python, plotly

Trying to use the `filter_query` in `style_data_conditional` to styling certain row in the dashtable. However, receive the error message.

Referring to the [Highlighting Text that Equals a Value](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting)

Error message:

> > DataTable filtering syntax is invalid for query: {column1} = "Grand Total"

> > (This error originated from the built-in JavaScript code that runs Dash apps. Click to see the full stack trace or open your browser's console.)

Code:

```
style_data_conditional=[{
                         'if': {
                                'filter_query': '{column1} = "Grand Total" ',
                                # 'column_id': 'column1'
                            },'backgroundColor': 'tomato',
                               'color': 'white'
                                                        
                         },]
```

Anyone know how to solve it or any advise on how to styling the row in dashtable?

Comment: Please add a full example of Dash, since it is very difficult to know the error without the entire program.

Comment: Does your `dash_table.DataTable(` have a columns attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out is the data issue. Cannot have space between the word.

`"Grand Total"` change to `"Grand_Total"`, then styling can function.